# Method to populate a map

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method to populate a map with some test data. I have created a class called player and i would like player object to be values in the map. When i try to compile the code bellow i recieve the message cannot find symbol - variable string.I am using bluej. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am under a little pressure at the moment.

```
    /**
     * Write a description of class Members here.
     * 
     * @author (your name) 
     * @version (a version number or a date)
     */
    public class Members
    {
       private Map<String, player>memberNumbers;

       /**
         * Constructor for objects of class Members
         */
       public Members()
       {
        memberNumbers = new HashMap<>();
       }

       /**
        * A method to populate the memberNumbers Map.
        * 
        */
       public void populateMap()
       {
          memberNumbers.put(String, player);

       }
    }
```

Comment: memberNumbers.put(String, player); is your problem. Its expecting a String and you are passing a keyword representing an inbuilt class

Comment: You know what a map does? If yes, what do you think, `memberNumbers.put(String, player);` does?

Answer (score 2):

Use variable instances rather than type keywords when adding entries to a `Map`

```
Player newPlayer = new Player(...);
memberNumbers.put("player1", newPlayer);
```

Also Java naming conventions show that class names start with an uppercase letter, giving `Map<String, Player>` which will prevent confusing types with instances

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually instantiate the players:

```
memberNumbers.put("1 - Fred", new Player());
memberNumbers.put("2 - Bob", new Player());
// and so forth
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
public void populateMap()
       {
          memberNumbers.put(String, player);

       }
```

with

```
public void populateMap()
       {
          Player player= new Player(); 
          memberNumbers.put("some text", player);

       }
```